# Reducing space between personal info and quote in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

When using `moderncv` package to make my CV, how to reduce the space between the personal info (e.g. phone, email, etc) and the quote? This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227455/space-above-quote-in-moderncv-banking-style) was asking the exact same question, but I tried the latex code from the solution and it seems that it no longer works. Wondering if there's an up-to-date solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code modifies the quote style by adding a negative space (-2em in this example) before the quote, thus controlling the space between the quote and the previous information.

(moderncv 2022-02-21 v2.3.1)

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85, top=1.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}


\quote{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason
    is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I
    have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a
    canon for our understanding. }


\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\vspace*{-2em}\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    
    \section{Education}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
    \cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
            
\end{document}
```